# How to connect to mongodb atlas cluster to create new database using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently creating a multi-tenant application, where anytime new user signup using a particular route, it creates a database using the company name and also saves the info in my default database (test).

This was possible using my local MongoDB, but I could not achieve this using my mongo atlas account and i also pass my MongoDB at URL, but I could not achieve this

Here is the registration code

```
// @route   Post api/user/register
// @desc    Register New User
// @access  Public
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body)
  //Check Validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  try {
    const {
      name,
      email,
      password,
      company,
      password2,
      username,
      country,
      address } = req.body;

    const admin = await Admin.findOne({ email: email });

    if (admin) {
      res.status(400).json({
        errors: { msg: "User Already Exist" }
      });
    }
    const secretToken = generateRandomString(30);

    const newAdmin = new Admin({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      secretToken,
      company,
      username,
      country,
      address,
      connection: {
        domain: company,
        db: username,
        password: password
      },
    });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newAdmin.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        newAdmin.password = hash;
        newAdmin
          .save()
          .then(admin => {
            let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"; // want to change this to connect to mongodb url so it can create new database...

            MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
              if (err) throw err;
             const dbo = db.db(`${newAdmin.company}`);
              const details = {
                name: `${newAdmin.name}`,
                address: `${newAdmin.address}`,
                password: `${newAdmin.name = hash}`,
                role: 1,
                email: `${newAdmin.email}`,
                isVerified: true,
              };
              dbo.collection("users").insertOne(details, function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 document inserted");
                db.close();
              });
            });
            res.status(200).json("successfully create user and user database");
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

Here is my server.js that make user registration possible

```
const express = require("express");
const config = require("config");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

// Init App
const server = express();

// DB Config
mongoose
  .connect(config.get("mongoURI"), {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  }) // Let us remove that nasty deprecation warrning :)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Middleware
server.use(morgan("dev"));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// Routes
server.use("/api/start", require("./api/Start"));


// Config
server.listen(config.get("port"), () => console.log("server process runing", `${config.get("port")}`));
```

Comment: *"but I could not achieve this"* - This does not actually state any specific error or problem. If there is an error, then please post it, or better yet **please search for it** since it's likely a very common problem which others have encountered before from a similar mistake. Also removing irrelevant tags from your question. Tags related to the question asked, and not your project configuration or status. Hence "multi tenant" really has nothing to do with the question "I cannot connect to MongoDB". Please also not this is not a "chat". You are meant to provide a whole question with details.

Comment: Thank you Neil, what i am facing is how to create a new database in mongo atlas for every time a new user register using the route (register)

Comment: Again. **This is not a chat**. ( hence why previous "chatty" comments have been removed). You have not shown any specific problem or error in your question. You **need** to add it, or your question will most certainly be closed. And again, you probably should instead be searching for existing answers to what the specific error message is. Please add the detail, or search and find an existing answer and remove the question yourself.

Comment: Note also *"Cannot connect to Atlas Cluster"* is included in your question title. However the actual code demonstrated is attemtping to connect to `"mongodb://localhost:27017/"` and if the comment at that line is basically your question, then there are existing answers as well as extensive documentation. Closing until you can show any valid reason this should be otherwise.